# Work Item never shows up in Web Portal

Tags: tfs, tfs-web-access

I am using the TFS web portal and whenever i create a work item (task bug, ....) it never shows up on the different grids. On top of the grid i can se Query Results : 1 results found (1 currently selected).

If i hit the run query button then i get the work item in the pop up grid.

How can i fix this problem because it happend in every grid and i cant alway tell people to hit the run query button....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running TFS Web Portal in FireFox causes that problem.